# Show python return in windows command line

Tags: python

I am really new to python and have what i believe to be a very simple question. I have the python script goldmedal.py and i want to return the result of the this script to the command line.

I have been searching but i can not seem to find a straight forward answer. When i run goldmedal.py i want to show the return olympic_medal_counts_df into the command line. What should i add to the code so it returns the variable back to the command line.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

def create_dataframe():

    countries = ['Russian Fed.', 'Norway', 'Canada', 'United States',
                 'Netherlands', 'Germany', 'Switzerland', 'Belarus',
                 'Austria', 'France', 'Poland', 'China', 'Korea', 
                 'Sweden', 'Czech Republic', 'Slovenia', 'Japan',
                 'Finland', 'Great Britain', 'Ukraine', 'Slovakia',
                 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Australia', 'Croatia', 'Kazakhstan']

    gold = [13, 11, 10, 9, 8, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    silver = [11, 5, 10, 7, 7, 6, 3, 0, 8, 4, 1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
    bronze = [9, 10, 5, 12, 9, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 0, 1]

    d = {'countries': Series(countries), 'gold': Series(gold), 'silver':Series(silver), 'bronze': Series(bronze)}

    olympic_medal_counts_df = DataFrame(d)

    return olympic_medal_counts_df
```

Comment: Unless you *call* `create_dataframe` somewhere you aren't showing, there is no result from that script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a python file, save it with a `.py` extension.

Then create a `main` function

```
def main():
    df = create_dateframe()  # Note you need to call your other function
    print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then run the python script from the command prompt.

Comment: adding the if __name__ == "__main__": main() did the trick! Thank you, i will accept when i can in a few minutes